# What type of pointer is used in a Rust `array.each` parameter?

Tags: rust

Given this Rust example ([found here](http://pcwalton.github.io/blog/2013/03/18/an-overview-of-memory-management-in-rust/)):

```
struct Dog {
    name: ~str
}

fn dogshow() {
    let dogs: [~Dog * 3] = [
        ~Dog { name: ~"Spot"   },
        ~Dog { name: ~"Fido"   },
        ~Dog { name: ~"Snoopy" },
    ];

    // let winner: ~Dog = dogs[1]; // this would be a compile time error.
                                   // can't assign another name to a 
                                   // uniquely owned (`~`) pointer.

    for dogs.each |dog| {  // WTF? `dog` is a second pointer to dogs[x]. 
                           // That's not supposed to be allowed by `~` pointers.
                           // why is this not a compile time error?
        println(fmt!("Say hello to %s", dog.name));
    }
}
```

What type of pointer is the `dog` parameter of `.each`?

The declaration of the `dog` variable seems to break the rule that **uniquely owned** pointers (`~`) may only have one name at a time.

How is it possible to loop thru the `dogs` and assign each dog to the variable name `dog` without breaking the rules of uniquely owned (`~`) pointers?

Is `dog` a **Rust *Reference*** in this case (thus allowing another name to represent a borrowed pointer)? If so, *how do we know*? Rust References should use the `&` syntax, no?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you suspected, it's a reference. In the closure, the type of `dog` is `&~Dog`, which means a reference to a unique smart pointer to a `Dog`.

The rule for unique smart pointers isn't that there is only one way to access the data; rather, it's that each unique smart pointer is the only *direct* reference to the data it points to. You can still have multiple references *to* the unique smart pointer.

The reason why you didn't have to annotate `dog` with `&` is due to type inference: the Rust compiler knows the type of `each`, so you don't have to write `&` in the closure.

Comment: Perfect. This is the type of answer I was really hoping for. Not just the precise answer to the question, but also some insight into the design philosophy of the language. Thanks Patrick!

Answer (score 4):

A quick way to check is to let the compiler emit an error regarding the type of `dog`:

```
for dogs.each |dog| {
    let test: int = dog;
    println(fmt!("Say hello to %s", dog.name));
}
```

This shows the type of `dog` is a borrowed pointer of an owned box of Dog (`&~Dog`):

```
x.rc:20:24: 20:27 error: mismatched types: expected `int` but found `&~Dog` (expected int but found &-ptr)
x.rc:20         let test: int = dog;
                                ^~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

You could also check from the [signature of `core::vec::each`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.6/core/vec.html#function-each):

```
fn each<'r, T>(v: &'r [T], f: &fn(&'r T) -> bool)
```

This shows that if we provide a `[T]`, the function will be called with the arguments of type `&T`.